# background image won't appear in IE & Chrome

Tags: html, css, background-image

Everything seems to be rendering as expected in Firefox, but in Chrome and IE my background image will not render at all.

Could someone check my code and maybe offer some solutions that have worked in the past?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Treadstohne Group | Aviation Consulting Services | Stan Gadek</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
     color: #444444;
     font-family: helvetica, arial,sans-serif;
     font-style: none
     height:100%;
     min-height:100%;
     background-image: url("http://p3plcpnl0658.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:2083/cpsess9841192309/viewer/home%2fsgadek%2fpublic_html%2fimages/background.jpg")no-repeat cover;
     min-height:100%;
}
html {
     height:100%;
     min-height:100%;
}
#bg {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    /* Preserve aspet ratio */
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
h2  {
    font-size: 15px
}
#bodycontent{
     position:absolute;
     top:25%;
     left:35%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
}
#padding {
    width: 800px;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 25px;
     /* default fallback */
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) transparent;
    /* nice browsers */
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
hr {
    border: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    width: 800px
}
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #21759b;
    text-decoration: none
}
/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #21759b;
}
/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
</style>
<!--begin of analytics script-->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-48171310-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!--end of analytics script-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Treadstohne Group - Aviation Consulting Services">
    <meta name="keywords" content="aviation consulting services, treadstohne group, aviation, treadstohne, treadstone, stan gadek, airline consulting, airline industry, U.S. airline consulting, airline consultant ">
</head>
<div id="bg">
<body>
</div>
<div id="bodycontent">
<div id="padding">
<h1>Treadstohne Group</h1>
<h2>&nbsp;Aviation Consulting Services</h2>
<hr>
<h3>Treadstohne Group is not your typical aviation consulting firm.</h3>
      <p>With CEO and CFO expertise in strategic planning, operations, finance and restructuring in the aviation and aerospace sectors, TreadStohne Group offers business consulting and advisory services to senior management and directors. Our experience includes planning, financial modeling, aerospace manufacturing, supply chain management, M&amp;A, LEAN process in service environments, and labor/management relations. </p>
      <p>Recent engagements and associations include:</p>
            <ul>
                  <li>A commercial helicopter company providing services in the forestry, oil and gas, construction, and military sectors.</li>
                  <li>A large military charter and cargo operator.</li>
                  <li>Commuter airline undergoing a financial restructuring.</li>
                  <li>An aerospace manufacturer of private jet aircraft.</li>
                  <li>A regional avionics firm engaged in sales, installation and service.</li>
                  <li>Advisor to public equity for the evaluation of aviation and aerospace investments.</li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
      <p>Please contact Stan Gadek, Principal for more information at:</p>
      <p><a href="mailto:Stan.gadek@treadstohne.com">Stan.gadek@treadstohne.com</a><p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: To check your code, we need to see your code.

Comment: I replaced:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">                                                       not working still

Answer (score 2):

your markup is incorrect. You have this:

```
<div id="bg">
<body background="http://p3plcpnl0658.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:2083/cpsess9841192309/viewer/home%2fsgadek%2fpublic_html%2fimages/background.jpg">
</div>
```

when it should be something like:

```
<body style="background:url('http://p3plcpnl0658.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:2083/cpsess9841192309/viewer/home%2fsgadek%2fpublic_html%2fimages/background.jpg')">
```

You may also need to set the background-size , repeat and so on, but for the time being, this is your issue. Furthermore, I'd replace it like this:

**HTML markup**

```
<body>
your content
```

**then in CSS**

```
body{background:url('http://p3plcpnl0658.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:2083/cpsess9841192309/viewer/home%2fsgadek%2fpublic_html%2fimages/background.jpg') no-repeat cover}
```

Comment: good point with the meta tags - Martin, I made the changes you suggested and now it doesn't want to render in firefox...so frustrating!

Comment: what I gave you is very basic so it should work, you probably have some more issues since you really had a mess in your HTML, why don't you edit your question with your full HTML as you have it now so we can see what the problem is?

Comment: Martin, really appreciate your insight and working with me on this. I'm certainly not an expert!

Comment: try deleting that div with id bg you have just before and after the body tag, you don't need it at all and it's affecting teh layout

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
body {
 color: #444444;
 font-family: helvetica, arial,sans-serif;
 font-style: none
 height:100%;
 min-height:100%;
 background-image: url("http://p3plcpnl0658.prod.phx3.secureserver.net:2083/cpsess9841192309/viewer/home%2fsgadek%2fpublic_html%2fimages/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Not that that will fix your  issue for sure, but if you are using CSS why not use CSS?